# JDBC Connection between MATLAB and NEO4J

Tags: matlab, jdbc, neo4j

I am trying to setup a database connection (to neo4j) using its JDBC driver. I am using Database Explorer within 2014b.

I get the error message "Unable to find JDBC driver". I have tried adding the driver using javaaddpath ('D:\driver path\filename.jar') and then using any combination of this in the "Driver" field in Connection Parameters. I have also tried "edit classpath.txt" as suggested elsewhere but I can't save it (Access Denied).

So any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

Comment: Did you use the driver with dependencies? http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.1.4/

Comment: Would be interested what you want to achieve, ping me at michael at neo4j .org

Comment: The file that I have been using is: neo4j-jdbc-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
From you post this does not appear to be the latest version. I'll dowload the 2.1.4 versions abd thy them with and without dependencies.